# What are these group of words called?

Tags: difference

I know that there are phrasal verbs like loop up, look out, Pass away, etc.
But, I want to know what this type of words are called which are made up of two complete English words: overrun, outnumbered, turnover, etc. and these group of words are single word and not hyphenated words.

Comment: The correct construction is **this type of word** or **these types of words**

Comment: @RonaldSole Isn't *this type of words* correct? They are collection of particular type and that type is only one (compound type).

Comment: I put both queries into Google Books Ngram Viewer. The construction **this type of word** was approximately 5 times as popular as **this type of words**. The latter sounds foreign to my ears but I leave it to wiser souls to judge.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+type+of+word%2Cthis+type+of+words&year_start=1800&year_end=2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called [compound words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)).