# Is it "this type of words" or "these types of words" in following context?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

I am a English learner and recently asked a question. In my [description](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/264712/what-are-these-group-of-words-called?noredirect=1#comment494852_264712), I wrote following.

> I know that there are phrasal verbs like loop up, look out, Pass away, etc. But, I want to know what **this type of words** are called which are made up of two complete English words: overrun, outnumbered, turnover, etc. and these group of words are single word and not hyphenated words.

Someone pointed out saying that it should be "these types of words".
Is it correct? My intense is to say, *they (words) are collection of particular type and that type is only one (compound) type.*

Sorry, for being inquisitive. I am just trying to improve my language skills.

Comment: Your title says "this type of word" and your quote says "this type of word**s**". You probably should fix one of them so that the question becomes more clear. AFAIK, "this **type** of **words**" is not correct in _any_ context.

Comment: @ICloneable corrected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [These kind of/ this kind of/those kind of](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71548/these-kind-of-this-kind-of-those-kind-of)

Comment: See also: [“This kind of things” vs “These kinds of thing”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/68599/388431) on [english.SE]. The accepted answer there provides very good use cases.

Comment: @ICloneable not entirely. My intention is to say, **This particular type of collection of words.**

Comment: @ICloneable And I not sure but there is difference between "type of" and "kind of".

Comment: @ICloneable thank you